# How to keep track of large numbers of A/B and Multivariate experiments for optimizing websites?

Tags: php, mysql, web, analytics

How do you keep track of A/B testing results for millions of pageviews?
The website is running a LAMP stack, and has a separate mysql server just for analytics, so there is a lot of space for data, but the question is how to organize and plan for large A/B testing.

Are there any guidelines that are recommended for trying to manage such large A/B experiments (both in number of experiments as well as size of experiments)? 
Are there any common open-source tools that are used?

And if you know, How do Facebook/Google/LinkedIn manage their experiments? and have they released any open-source code?

Comment: I don't think anyone could give you an absolute answer without knowing anything about the changes you are testing and the relevant metrics which might be affected. In case it's all about product and has nothing to do with technical improvemnts - you should probably use a 3rd party web analytics service such as Google Analytics or Omniture and make sure you set it up with very detailed custom reports relevant to your A/B test.

Comment: @Saggi: I was specifically hoping there would be open source tools that allow for A/B testing on large data sets. All I need is a function call to insert in my code when I am running a variation, and another function call when it is a "success".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used [Google Website Optimizer](https://www.google.com/analytics/siteopt/splash?hl=en) to track multiple AB and Multivariant tests. It has nice reporting features too.